# Doxygen: show proccesed comments

Tags: comments, show, doxygen

I've got a project on C code, and it's required that code is linked from documentation. Doxygen do it pretty well, but... It hides processed comments.
Is there a way/option to show this comments in the HTML window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try setting `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS` to `NO` in the config file?